# Are there generally accepted/expected practices for writing program notes for your own compositions?

Tags: composition

Whenever I need to write program notes for a call for scores, I am not quite sure what the proper format for them is. Should I write it in first person or third person? Should program notes I write for my own works include information about myself as well as the piece? Is there a standardized style guide for program notes?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

What I have observed is that if one is the composer, use the first person. If one is commenting on others' works, write in the third. It's always useful to the reader to know the relationship between the program note writer and the music note writer.